# How to read a Nexus Maven repository with disabled anonymous access?

Tags: java, maven, nexus, nexus3

In Nexus 3 I created a group maven repository. This repository aggregates a couple of proxies(maven central, archive...) as well as some internal repos. It works fine with the anonymous incoming requests activated. Now I have to disable the anonymous reads for the security reasons. I have a user that has the nx_admin privilege and my settings.xml mirror section looks like this:

```
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>group-repository</id>
            <name>Group Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.xxxxx.intern/repository/xxx/</url>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    ...
    <servers>
       <server>
          <id>group-repository</id>
          <username>johndoe</username>
          <password>xxxxxx</password>
       </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

now I cannot download any dependency from the repository:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from group-repository: http://repository.xxxxx.intern/repository/xxx/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.3.5.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ line 8, column 11
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for xx.yyyy:zzzzzz:${buildVersion}: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.5.RELEASE from/to group-repository (http://repository.xxxxx.intern/repository/xxx/): Failed to transfer file http://repository.xxxxx.intern/repository/xxx/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.3.5.RELEASE.pom with status code 503 and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 10, column 10
```

I also have a deployment section with the user authentication and it works fine.
Anyone any idea what I may miss?

Comment: Status 503 means "service unavailable". So the problem is probably on the server side.

Comment: @JFabianMeier my bad, instead of deactivating the anonymous account, I took the repository offline(there is a flag for it "If checked, the repository accepts incoming requests"). Please write it as an answer so I can vote it up.